# Docker - Replacement for `dockerd` on Mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

I wanted to start the docker daemon with an open TCP address like this: `docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375`, but the terminal suggested that I use `dockerd` instead, which is apparently not a program that comes with the Docker Client for mac. Is there a way I can either

- A - get some form of `dockerd` on my mac machine.
- B - get around the use of `dockerd` by some other method.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the config of mac docker like dockerd.

Click the docker icon in the menu bar, preferences, advanced

[image: docker config]

Comment: Maybe you can give steps on how you were able to do that

Comment: ^ click the docker icon in the menu bar, preferences, advanced

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Updated.

Comment: @YongHaoHu, seriously a year? :)

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada  I don't play stackoverflow much time at that time. And I lost your reply. Sry. -_-

Comment: @DeanChristianArmada Sure. ;P

Answer (score 7):

Install socat command: `brew install socat`
Choose a port: (in the example 8099)
Run: `socat -d -d TCP-L:8099,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock`
and then use `tcp://localhost:8099` as **API URL**

works for me, hope this helps

Comment: How does this help with the question, which was about finding dockerd for mac?

Answer (score 3):

> get around the use of `dockerd` by some other method. (2016)

Note that in 2022, you can go without `dockerd`/Docker Desktop entirely.

See **[Batuhan Apaydin](https://twitter.com/developerguyba)**'s article "[A modern toolkit to start working with container images on macOS that meets your needs without requiring a Docker Daemon or even Docker Desktop](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/a-modern-toolkit-to-start-working-with-container-images-on-macos-that-meets-your-needs-without-caa0f38529de)".

It uses [`lima`](https://github.com/lima-vm/lima)+[`nerdctl`](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl)

The `nerdctl` tool is designed as a drop-in replacement for the Docker client

And **Lima is a hypervisor that launches Linux virtual machines with automatic file sharing, port forwarding, and `containerd`**.

The name of lima comes from an abbreviation of the first two capital letters of **LI**nux **MA**chines.

The design of Lima is similar to WSL2, but Lima focuses on macOS as the primary target host.
Lima uses QEMU, which is a generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer, as a hypervisor under the hood to achieve the virtualization thing.

Lima can also work with other container engines such as Podman and even for non-container applications.

By default, when lima launches a VM, it runs `buildkitd` and `containerd` in a rootless way and also downloads necessary client tooling around them such as `buildctl`, `nerdctl`.
Everything will be set up for us. So, all that’s left is building, pulling, and running containers

For `buildkit`, Batuhan proposes [`developer-guy/buildkit-machine`](https://github.com/developer-guy/buildkit-machine)

> `buildkit-machine` allows you to make `buildkitd` daemon accessible in your macOS environment.
>
> To do so, it uses `lima,` which is a Linux subsystem for macOS, under the hood.
> `lima` spins up a VM that runs `buildkitd` daemon in a rootless way which means that sock file of the `buildkitd` daemon is now be able to accessible from `/run/user/<USERID>/buildkit/buildkitd`.

So: no more Docker Desktop / `dockerd`, and use container in a rootless mode!

For more, see **[Bret Fisher](https://podcast.bretfisher.com/about)**'s video "[Free Docker Desktop Alternatives: DevOps and Docker Live Show (Ep 156)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXog5BrWXeM)" (Jan. 2022)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this in the official forum

https://forums.docker.com/t/using-pycharm-docker-plugin-with-docker-beta/8617/9

```
$socat TCP-LISTEN:2376,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

> That workaround opens port 2376 to the world... as TLS isn't enabled, this is a bad idea as anyone on the same network can hijack your docker daemon

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported to run dockerd on Mac. From [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27102#issuecomment-251164008):

> I think on Darwin it should never suggest to run dockerd. The daemon runs in a Linux virtual machine, so you do not need to (and cannot) run it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any specific configuration on mac, you might have already installed Docker Desktop. Docker desktop supports configuration using UserInterface shown below in the screenshot.

[image]